# How to add icon from kml file to mapkit in swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, kml

I have a kml file:

After the show all data from kml file on map kit is okay. but in kml file I can't show the icon.

[image]

This is the icon in the kml file: 
[image]

This is an annotation code:

```
open class KMLDocument: KMLElement {
     open var overlays: [MKOverlay] = []
     open var annotations: [KMLAnnotation] = []
     open var styles: [String: KMLStyle] = [:]
     open var placemarks: [KMLPlacemark] = []

     public convenience init(_ element: AEXMLElement, generateMapKitClasses: Bool) {
        self.init(element)
        if generateMapKitClasses {
            initOverlay()
            initAnnotation()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func initAnnotation() {
        for pointPlacemark: KMLPlacemark in placemarks {
            if let point: KMLPoint = pointPlacemark.point {
                let annotation = KMLAnnotation(point.coordinates)
                annotation.title = pointPlacemark.name
                annotation.subtitle = pointPlacemark.description
                annotation.style = pointPlacemark.style
                self.annotations.append(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for an icon image in a KML file to show up correctly in Google Earth or Maps, the icon image needs to be publicly accessible.  When I put the URL for your icon image into my browser (https://www.svgimages.com/svg-image/s5/send-file-256x256.png), I just get a black screen and no image. So for whatever reason, that URL is not returning a valid, publicly accessible image file.  It might work ok in a KML viewer that has special access to that server and can get the image, but probably won't work anywhere else.  You might also want to check that it's actually returning a PNG file, and not an SVG file (since the URL contains "svg" in two places), since KML only supports JPG, PNG, and GIF images (plus TIFF and GeoTiff for overlays).